# jQuery ajax not show and hide the loader div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am calling php code using jquery ajax function, but I wan to show a loader div while sending the request and after complete the request hide the div.For testing purpose just I hold the php execution 5seconds using **sleep(5)** method, show should I can see this loader. It is not working for me I had try the following code

**First Try**

```
show_loader();
   $.ajax(
    {
      async: false,
      url: "bindanswerposts.php",
      data: "sessuserid="+sessuserid+"&postid=" + _ViewPostid + "&xcode=" + $("body").data("xcode"),
      type: "POST",

      success: function(resp)
      {
        hideloader();
      },
      error: function(e)
      {        
        hideloader();
      }
    });
```

**Second Try**

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    showloader();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    hideloader();
});  

       $.ajax(
        {
          async: false,
          url: "bindanswerposts.php",
          data: "sessuserid="+sessuserid+"&postid=" + _ViewPostid + "&xcode=" + $("body").data("xcode"),
          type: "POST",

          success: function(resp)
          {

          },
          error: function(e)
          {        

          }
        });
```

**Third Try**

```
           $.ajax(
            {
              async: false,
              url: "bindanswerposts.php",
              data: "sessuserid="+sessuserid+"&postid=" + _ViewPostid + "&xcode=" + $("body").data("xcode"),
              type: "POST",
               beforeSend: function() {
       showloader();
      },
      complete: function() {
       hidloader();
  },
              success: function(resp)
              {

              },
              error: function(e)
              {        

              }
            });
```

But every above methods are not worked, please help me. But in normal javascript **ajaxRequest** is working fine.

```
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 1)
   {
      showloader();
   }

   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
   {
      hideloader();
   }
 }
```

Comment: can you post showloader and hideloader functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `complete` method of ajax.

Make sure that you've `loader` in your DOME.

```
<div id="loading" style="display: none"><img src="loading.gif"></div>
```

Ajax call

```
//Show loader here
$( "#loading" ).show();
$.ajax({
       //async: false,
       url: "bindanswerposts.php",
       data: "sessuserid="+sessuserid+"&postid=" + _ViewPostid + "&xcode=" + $("body").data("xcode"),
       type: "POST",
       success: function(resp)
       {

       },
       error: function(e)
       {        

       },
       complete:function()
       {
          //Hide the loader over here
          $('#loading').hide();
       }
});
```

**EDIT** Remove `async=false`, it should work.

- For synchronous ajax call, it does NOT. Ajax gets executed first and all other processes are blocked/queued.

Comment: what's the issue you're facing ? any errors in console ?

Comment: No errors, If I used debugger it is working fine. but not working without using debugger.

Comment: Try to put your code inside $(document).ready(function(){ }); and remove the async false one to check it, if it's still having problem just create jsfiddle to check the exact problem and your code.

Comment: Thank you very much, It is working perfect when I removed the async:false. Please update your answer I will tick your answer and vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may work for you first create put a loader gif image where ypu want to show loader default css property as display:none;

```
<img src="loader.gif" class="loader" style="display:none;">
```

Then show when your ajax executed like this

```
$(".loader").show();
$.ajax(
{
  async: false,
  url: "bindanswerposts.php",
  data: "sessuserid="+sessuserid+"&postid=" + _ViewPostid + "&xcode=" + $("body").data("xcode"),
  type: "POST",

  success: function(resp)
  {
     $(".loader").hide();
  },
  error: function(e)
  {        
    $(".loader").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face to the same issue, and I tried different approach but not worked.
So I did it by using the following approach.
*You can adjust it according to your requirements.*

```
<div class="spinner" id="dietLoadingSpinner" style="display: none;"></div>
```

When creating AJAX request by button click

```
$("body").on("click", "#foodsearch", function(e){
    $(".dietLoadingSpinner").show();
       setTimeout(function() {
           createAjaxRequest()
    }, 200);
});
```

Hide it when request done.

```
function createAjaxRequest() {
   ...
     $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      $(".dietLoadingSpinner").hide();
        console.log(response);
   });
   ...
}
```